# Download PDF, saving to document directory and loading it in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, directory, document

I am having problem with download pdf, saving to document directory and loading it in web view.
I have no experience with download things, saving things to directories and UIWebView before.

Before I ask this question, I've search multiple StackOverflow question and tried my best but it still doesn't work.

**First This is how I download the PDF from url and save it to document directory**

```
let myURL = URL(string: "https://example/example/product.pdf")
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(url: myURL!)

do {
    let theData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(urlRequest as URLRequest, returning: nil)
    var docURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last as? NSURL
    docURL = docURL?.appendingPathComponent("my.pdf") as NSURL?
    try theData.write(to: docURL as! URL)
    print("downloaded")
} catch (let writeError) {
    print("error : \(writeError)")
}
```

The application pauses for a while and prints "downloaded"

**This is how I check the list of contacts in my document directory**

```
 let docURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last)
        do{
            let contents = try (FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: docURL!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsHiddenFiles))
            print("There are")
            print(contents)
        }
        catch (let error)
        {
            print("error contents \(error)")
        }
```

It prints "There are [file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DF6A310C-EB7E-405E-9B1B-654486B5D03A/Documents/my.pdf]"

**This is how I load the pdf into webView**

```
var webView = UIWebView(frame : vc.view.frame)
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
var documentsDirectory = paths[0]
var filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("my.pdf").absoluteString
var targetURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
webView.loadRequest(request)
vc.view.addSubview(webView)
```

The WebView comes up but shows nothing. I'm really confused if my.pdf is really saved with readable PDF format.

I don't know if there are some stuffs like I have to add something in info.plist or enable something in app capabilities. Thank you very much.

Comment: Apart from your question `NSURLConnection` is deprecated use `NSURLSession` now

Comment: hi @thura oo if possible i request you to give your working code as an answer so that someone can get help or learn from it.In my case i'm having same scenario as yours but not able to figure out how to do this step by step. Please help me with your code.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look through all of the code but the following two lines are a problem:

```
var filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("my.pdf").absoluteString
var targetURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
```

The value of `URL absoluteString` does not give you a file path so the value of `filePath` is not a valid value for the `URL fileURLWithPath:` initializer.

And what's the point of going from `URL` to `String` (as a path) and back to a `URL`? Simply combine those two lines into:

```
var targetURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("my.pdf")
```

As a side note, use some consistency. In other code you get the Documents folder URL using:

```
let docURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last)
```

and in other code you use:

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
var documentsDirectory = paths[0]
var ... = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory)...
```

Pick one approach and use it consistently. Since you need a `URL`, use the first approach. This means the code I suggested should now be:

```
let docURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!
let targetURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("my.pdf")
```

Comment: Those lines of codes are new to me and I really messed up writing them. I did as you said and it works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy can you guide me step by step for 1) how to create directory 2) how to save pdf file from url in newly created directory 3) how to share that pdf file from that directory 4) after sharing is done how to delete that directory. Please help me.If you want to me to ask as an question will also do it for this.